# How do I remove this white mist from my Terraria world?

Tags: terraria

In Teraria, I have recently started a world and there is a mist effect. This is very annoying -- how do I get rid of it?

[image: this is my base filled with annoying fog it is also outside a bit]

Answer (score 11):

That looks like the mist that appears in a [Graveyard](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Graveyard). You can get rid of it by using your pickaxe to remove any tombstones or grave markers in the area.